# NSString add tags around occurrences of string

Tags: ios, replace, nsstring

I need to replace a string like so;

```
NSString *temp = @"this is a sentence";
```

with

```
NSString *temp = @"this is a <span style=\"color:red\">sentence</span>"
```

Now I can do this with the following line;

```
temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sentence" withString:@"<span style=\"color:red\">sentence</span>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
```

Now the problem with using the above is that I don't know what case either the replacing or replaced string will be in. I can get around this by using the insensitive search but I need the replaced string to be in the same format as the original in the final output.

*Edit*

I've overly simplified my problem so it's easier to understand, but essentially I need to stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString whilst ignoring upper/lower case but at the same time keeping the same upper/lower case on the final string.

Comment: might need more info but seems like you have a specialized enough case to write your own string replace. It's not that complicated of a thing to do.

Comment: Got any examples? I figured i'd have to do some kind of custom string replace.

Comment: try using regex. It helps a lot when it comes to searching and replacing complex things. (Regular Expression -- NSRegularExpressionSearch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a "regular expression" replace, where `$0` in the replacement string
refers to the actually found substring:

```
NSString *temp = @"this is a foo, or a FOO";
NSString *result = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"foo"
                    withString:@"<span>$0</span>"
                       options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
```

Result:

```
this is a <span>foo</span>, or a <span>FOO</span>
```

But note that any regular expression "special characters" in the search pattern have to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions to find "sentence" and add your tags around it.

The *$1* refers to the matched regex group *(sentence)*.

The *\b* indicates a word boundary in the regular expression. If you don't include it, a word like "asentenceb" will be matched as well.

```
NSString *test = @"my test sentence is a Sentence. Oh yes, a sEnTenCe!";
NSRange testRange = NSMakeRange(0, test.length);

// Create regex object
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b(sentence)\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

// Replace matches with template
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:test options:0 range:testRange withTemplate:@"<span style=\"color:red\">$1</span>"];
```

Note: You could probably do somethign similar with *stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString*.

Answer (score 0):

check if 
    `<span style=\"color:red\">sentence</span>`
is in your nsstring. and if not, replace the original nsstring with the new nsstring

Comment: i think you're misunderstanding. I've overly simplified my problem so its easier to understand, but essentially i need to stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString whilst ignoring upper/lower case but at the same time keeping the same upper/lower case on the final string.